# Python: How to evaluate a part of each item in a list, and append matching results?

Tags: python, list

**Problem:**

- Trying to evaluate first 4 characters of each item in list.
- If the first 4 chars match another first 4 chars in the list, then append the last three digits to the first four. See example below.

**Notes:**

- The list values are not hard coded.
- The list always has this structure "####.###".
- Only need to match first 4 chars in each item of list.
- Order is not essential.

**Code:**

```
Grid = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "194P.005", "194P.015", "093T.021", "093T.102", "094G.032"]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Grid = ["094G.016\019\032", "194P.005\015", "093T.021\102"]
```

**Research:**

- I know that sets can find duplicates, could I use a set to evaluate only the 1st 4 chars, would I run into a problem since indexing of sets cannot be done?
- Would it be better to split the list items into the 2 parts. The four digits before the period ("094G"), and a separate list of the three digits after the period ("093"), compare them, then join them in a new list?
- Is there a better way of doing this all together that I'm not realizing?

Comment: What if there are 3 items containing the same first 4 digits?

Comment: Using a dict with the first 4 chars as keys would be an efficient solution.

Comment: Is the order important?  Otherwise you could use a dictionary with the chars before the period as the key, and the rest as a value.  Where there are duplicates you use a list for the value.

Comment: @Thrustmaster "094G.016\019\032" if three items. Each matching item would be appended.

Comment: @cdarke I think I can make do without order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one straightforward way to do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

grid = ['094G.016', '094G.019', '194P.005', '194P.015', '093T.021', '093T.102', '094G.032']
d = defaultdict(list)

for item in grid:
    k,v = item.split('.')
    d[k].append(v)

result = ['%s.%s' % (k, '/'.join(v)) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Gives unordered `result`:

```
['093T.021/102', '194P.005/015', '094G.016/019/032']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll most likely want is a dictionary mapping the first part of each code to a list of second parts. You can build the dictionary like so:

```
mappings = {}    #Empty dictionary
for code in Grid:  #Loop over each code
    first, second = code.split('.')   #Separate the code into first.second
    if first in mappings:     #if the first was already found
        mappings[first].append(second)  #add the second to those already computed
    else:
        mappings[first] = [second]   #otherwise, put it in a new list
```

Once you have the dictionary, it will be quite simple to loop over it and combine the second parts together (ideally, using `'\\'.join`)

Comment: You'd want a defaultdict in this case so you don't need to check if the key already exists

Comment: I went with the simplest case to make it easier to understand what was happening

Comment: I also didn't know about defaultdict until now

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `defaultdict`.

```
from containers import defaultdict

grid = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "194P.005", "194P.015", "093T.021", "093T.102"]
d = defaultdict(set)

for item in grid:
    prefix, suffix = item.split(".")
    d[prefix].add(suffix)

output = [ "%s.%s" % (prefix, "/".join(d[prefix]), ) for prefix in d ]
```

Comment: p.s. I assumed you don't want duplicate suffixes, so I used a `set` for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> Grid = ["094G.016", "094G.019", "194P.005", "194P.015", "093T.021", "093T.102", "094G.032"]
>>> Grid = sorted(Grid, key=lambda x:x.split(".")[0])
>>> gen = ((k, g) for k, g in groupby(Grid, key=lambda x:x.split(".")[0]))
>>> gen = ((k,[x.split(".") for x in g]) for k, g in gen)
>>> gen = list((k + '.' + '/'.join(x[1] for x in g) for k, g in gen))
>>> for x in gen:
...     print(x)
...
093T.021/102
094G.016/019/032
194P.005/015
```